# RTF File in Apex

Tags: apex, json

Can anybody point me in the right direction for handling RTF files in apex?

I'm making a REST request which is returning a JSON response containing RTF encoded text, example below, and I'm unsure of what to do with it to either save it as a document or display it somehow.

`\\rtf1\\fbidis\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\\f1\\fswiss\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\\f2\\fswiss\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\ltrpar\\sa200\\sl276\\slmult1\\qc\\f0\\fs17{\\pict\\wmetafile8\\picw28222\\pich6244\\picwgoal5759\\pichgoal1274 \r\n010009000003fa3d03000000d13d030000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000\r\n000c02ed002c04030000001e0004000000070104000400000007010400d13d0300410b2000cc00\r\nb100200300000000ec002b04000000002800000020030000b10000000100180000000000607b06\r\n0000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\r\nffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

Comment: What's the objective? Saving the blob as an attachment is going to be your easiest path, since Salesforce Rich Text is HTML, not RTF.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed I think saving as an attachment will be a good step forward but the ideal would be being able to display the contents of the RTF in a Visualforce page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce's Rich Text fields are encoded in HTML, not RTF, so the system itself is not going to help you here.

Inasmuch as designing an RTF parser in Apex is likely to be prohibitively complex and limited in functionality, your best course is probably going to be

- Saving the RTF blob as an Attachment or ContentDocument in Salesforce.
- Using something like [rtf.js](https://github.com/tbluemel/rtf.js) (disclaimer: not my project; haven't used it) to render the RTF file dynamically in a Visualforce page.

Alternately, you could implement a web service off-Salesforce (on Heroku, for example) to ingest the RTF and convert it to a more palatable format, like HTML or PDF, and re-inject that data into Salesforce.